# Umlauts or other UFT8 characters in Chrome Notifications

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

Does anybody know how I can use German umlauts such as ö, ä, ü in a Chrome Notification message. When I add a message like

```
chrome.notifications.create('note', {
  type: 'image',
  title: 'Test title',
  message: 'Message with ü'
})
```

I get a strange symbol instead of the umlaut. Also, adding the HTML code ü or Ü does not work. Many thanks for your advice!

Comment: Check your js file encoding, it should be UTF-8.

Comment: You made my day, bro! I had indeed set my js file encoding to UFT-8 throughout the code via "charset = UFT8". But after giving your advice some more thought, I found out that my code editor saved the files in the wrong encoding :-) Shame on me, I should have realized this much earlier. But thanks for opening my eyes...